# Create a map of characters and their associated bitstrings from a huffman tree

Tags: c++, dictionary, tree, tree-traversal, huffman-code

I have coded the tree and now I am trying to traverse the tree and create a bitstring for each character and put these values into a map.

Here is my code so far:

```
map<char, string> build_encoding_map(freq_info*& huffman_root) 
{
    map<char, string> ret;
    string char_code;
    char symbol;

    if (huffman_root->left == NULL && huffman_root->right == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Your tree is empty." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (huffman_root->is_leaf = false)
        {
            if (huffman_root->left != NULL)
            {
                huffman_root = huffman_root->left;
                char_code += ".";
                //add a bit to the bit string
            }
            else if (huffman_root->right != NULL)
            {
                huffman_root = huffman_root->right;
                char_code += "^";
        }
        symbol = huffman_root->symbol;
        ret[symbol] = char_code;
        huffman_root->is_leaf = false; //So that I don't have repeat characters in the map

        //ret.insert(std::make_pair(symbol, char_code));
        //Need to delete the leaf node  
    }
    //traverse the tree until is_leaf is true
    //add turns taken (left"." or right"^") to the string
    //insert the character in the found leaf and it's associated string to the map  
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more specific. I want to do this recursively, but because I am a beginner, I don't see what part I should make recursive. Also, I am not sure how to make it traverse the whole tree and find all of the leaves. Really, I just want someone to look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong.